# Kafka consumer is continuously printing Consumer exception

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using a spring boot application with spring kafka configured to read messages from Kafka.

Spring Boot version: 3.2.3
Spring Kafka version: 3.1.1

My consumer is throwing up below error in the application logs

```
Logging Level: ERROR
Message text: Consumer exception
Class name: org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer
```

I could see several occurance of the same text getting printed every millisecond and there is a huge flood of these ERRORs.

My Kafka consumer is already configured with a Listener error handle as described below.

`My Consumer`

```
@KafkaListener(id = "test-1", topics = "my-test-topic", groupId = "my-test-consumer-group", **errorHandler = "kafkaEventErrorHandler"**)
```

`The custom handler looks as shown below`

```
public class KafkaEventErrorHandler<T> implements ConsumerAwareListenerErrorHandler {

  @Override
  public Object handleError(Message<?> message, ListenerExecutionFailedException e,
      Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
    log.error("Message Headers : {}", message.getHeaders());
    log.trace("Message Payload : {}", message.getPayload());
    log.error("Exception StackTrace : {}", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
    log.info("Consumer Metrics: {}", consumer.metrics().toString());
    return null;
  }
}
```

On top of this, I am also using the

```
DefaultErrorHandler
```

configured as a bean with the below reference:

```
  @Bean
  public DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler() {
    BackOff fixedBackOff = new FixedBackOff(500, 3);
    DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler((consumerRecord, backoff) -> {
    }, fixedBackOff);
    errorHandler.addRetryableExceptions(SocketTimeoutException.class);
    errorHandler.addNotRetryableExceptions(NullPointerException.class);
    return errorHandler;
  }
```

I am really surprised and curious to understand how did the failure miss these error handlers and is throwing up only the message "Consumer exception".

At the moment, I am not aware of the cause the issue. I would like to know 2 things

1. How can I extract/print the actual exception stack trace from the

```
KafkaMesageListenerContainer
```

using my existing error handler.

2. If that is not possible, Kindly suggest any alternative way to achive this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `KafkaEventErrorHandler` is a type of `KafkaListenerErrorHandler`. Here is something from it's javadoc.

```
/**
 * An error handler which is called when a {@code @KafkaListener} method
 * throws an exception. This is invoked higher up the stack than the
 * listener container's error handler.
```

This means that this error handler will be called much earlier than the `DefaultErrorHnalder` which is a `CommonErrorHandler`. I think there is something wrong with the way you configure the `errorHandler` property on the `KafkaListener`, because it doesn't seem like it is finding it properly. I would suggest adding a breakpoint in your `KafkaEventErrorHandler` and see if it is invoked. The specific message that you are seeing is coming from this section of the container: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/main/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java#L1968

So, its either the `DefaultErrorHandler` is not picked up by the container, or it did and then it's handle method threw an exception. Debugging via your app could tell you what's going on. If you still have trouble, please share with us a small reproducible sample application and we can take a look at this further.